# Adding a Node in a doubly-linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working on some code were I need to add a Node into a doubly-linked list. This is the code I have so far:

```
Node tempNext = cursor.getNext();
temp = new Node(item, null, cursor, tempNext);
tempNext.setPrev(temp);
```

Where `cursor` is the Node that is right before where the new added Node should go.

How do I set the other nodes to correctly maintain the state of the doubly-linked list?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. I've edited it with a guess, based upon your acceptance of the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing meaningful variable names will always help you, never use names like temp*:

```
protected void insertNodeAfter(Node currentNode, Node newNode) {
    Node displacedNode = currentNode.getNext();
    currentNode.setNext(newNode);
    newNode.setNext(displacedNode)
    displacedNode.setPrev(newNode);
    newNode.setPrev(currentNode);
}
```

Comment: -1 for answering a homework question with functional code.

Comment: You are right Bill, I deserve it.

Comment: @BillK See the FAQ. There is nothing against answering homework questions if they are formulated clearly and can serve as a useful reference for others.

Comment: I have no problem with answering homework questions, I think it's one of the better uses of SO, however it's just wrong to give a full answer to copy down--you give guidance that can help them solve the problem on their own or code snips that can clear up syntax while still allowing them to learn otherwise you are not helping anyone--it's just common sense.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like all you need to add is

```
cursor.setNext(temp);
```

Do you have a specific question?

Comment: So:
Node tempNext = cursor.getNext();
temp = new Node(item, null, cursor, tempNext);      tempNext.setPrev(temp);      cursor.setNext(temp);
Will successfully add a Node to the linked-list correct?

Comment: It should, assuming the Node constructor you are using correctly sets the next and previous nodes for your new node.  Also, @rodrigoap is absolutely right about meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addItemBefore( int info )
{
    previousItem = new ListItem( previousItem, info, this );
}
```